# How to evaluate a regression model's sensitivity to noise

Tags: regression, sensitivity-analysis

How can I investigate the sensitivity of a regression model to noise?

A basic idea is to add some (Gaussian) noise to the dependent and/or independent variables and (re)evaluate the RMSE.

However, the problem with this approach is, that one is mostly interested in modeling the true data, and not the noisy data. 
Hence, is it reasonable to measure the RMSE on the original dependent variable, not the noisy one, even if the latter has been used for model building?

Comment: IMHO it seems reasonable. That is, to split the original data set into a training set and a test set, add noise to the training set, train the model, then evaluate on the test set (the one without noise). I believe this should show how sensitive is the regression model to the noise. Do you have any news regarding your experiment?